# What is the proper way plot multiple lambda function in plotnine so legend appears?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, plotnine

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175495/plotnine-doesnt-add-legend) looks like it's fairly close to the answer I'm looking for but it's not quite there. Perhaps I'm not following the "tidy data" principles and will need to make a dataframe evaluated at many points to plot these functions but I'm hesitant to accept that as the answer.

Here's the code to plot the graph I have.

```
call_value_per_unit = lambda s_t1,X: max(0, s_t1-X)
put_value_per_unit = lambda s_t1, X: max(0, X-s_t1)
put_call_value = lambda s_t1, X: put_value_per_unit(s_t1, X) + call_value_per_unit(s_t1, X)

independent_variable = "Stock Price"
dependent_variable = "Asset Price"

g = ggplot(pd.DataFrame({independent_variable:[10,20]}), aes(x=independent_variable)) \
         + stat_function(fun=put_value_per_unit, args=[15], color="red") \
         + stat_function(fun=call_value_per_unit, args=[15], color="blue") \
         + stat_function(fun=put_call_value, args=[15], color="black") \
         + ylab(dependent_variable) \
         + ggtitle(" ".join([independent_variable , "vs", dependent_variable]))
_ = g.draw()
```

But there's no legend... And I'd like there to be one.

(Although I'm in python, R users will likely have good suggestions)

Comment: which field you want as legend and what kind of plot are you expecting?

Comment: I'd like the function lines to be labeled

Comment: It's fairly easy to plot with tidy approach. are you ok with that?

Comment: I suppose. To make sure I understand the tidy approach, I'd make a dataframe with these functions evaluated at many points, and then plot them using geom_line?

Comment: R programmer here. Shouldn't there be a `geom_*` like `geom_point`? Or, in `stat_function`, a `stat = "point"` or `"line"` or other value?

Comment: @RuiBarradas You are right. There is nothing like stat_function, and as you mentioned it's either geom_* or stat_* (e.g.: stat_count(geom = "bar") ..

Comment: @financial_physician I understand, but output of the functions should be part of data frame or it could be complex to plot. would you be able to share sample data?

Comment: @Neel I'm actually not working with any data. I'm just trying to make some pretty graphs and ggplot has been good for data plots. Maybe I should use a different tool since I'm not working with a dataset right now

Comment: @RuiBarradas what do R programmers usually use if they just want to plot some functions on a graph?

Comment: In base graphics, `curve`. In ggplot, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting multiple functions in one plot and having a legend for each function is not possible. For `stat_function`, `func` is a parameter not an aesthetic so you cannot map a variable/column to it. Legends only help interpret aesthetic mappings.

Since you want to do heavy many computations, do that outside the plotting calls then plot the results with `geom_line`. Make sure your dataframe is in [tidy data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data) form. Do not let the fact that there is a `stat_function` force you into using when it is not the best tool for the job.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, it walks through what's wrong with what I want to do, why I should do it differently, and then how to go about it differently. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In R, to plot functions with package `ggplot2`, first define a data set with a `x` vector. Then use `stat_function` with an appropriate `geom`. This usually is one of

- `geom = "line"`
- `geom = "point"`

Then, it's very simple to graph the function.

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(x = -5:5)

ggplot(df1, aes(x)) +
  stat_function(geom = "line", fun = function(x) x^2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rul! Really appreciate the insight